# Use ipdb in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, ipdb

Debugging Python code in Eclipse is often two heavyweight, so I often prefer pdb.set_trace() for a quick check of my code. However ipdb offers a couple of nice features like tab-completion and syntax-highlighting. Is it possible to use ipdb in Eclipse as well?

```
import numpy as np
import ipdb

test = np.arange(10)
ipdb.set_trace()
```

Leads to:

```
> [1;32m/home/hypercube/pythoncode/src/test.py[0m(6)[0;36m<module>[1;34m()[0m
  [1;32m      4 [1;33m[0mtest[0m [1;33m=[0m [0mnp[0m[1;33m.[0m[0marange[0m[1;33m([0m  [1;36m10[0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m[0m[0m[0m[1;32m      5 [1;33m[1;33m[0m[0m[0m[1;32m----> 6
  [1;33m[0mipdb[0m[1;33m.[0m[0mset_trace[0m[1;33m([0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m  [0m[0m[0m
  ipdb>
```

So I can get to the ipdb debugger and get information on my code, however tab-completion does not work, syntax-highlighting looks weird and most of all there are these strange text strings. I already set encoding to UTF. Do you have any experience in this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/
worked for me in aptana (which is pretty much eclipse). Gives a neat button in the console for enable/disable too.

Not sure about tab completion though sorry.